# Highlight / Unhighlight menu item with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

On page load I want to highlight a menu item and unhighlight it again after a second. I want to accomplish sort of a Knight Rider effect but only in one direction. From left to right and it should stop when it has traversed all the menu items. This way I want to put more attention on my menu bar.

My HTML:

```
<div id="header">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a class="menu-item-link">Stage1</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a class="menu-item-link">Stage2</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.highlight { color: #FFFFFF; }

$(document).ready(function () {
$(".menu-item a").each(function () {
        $(this).addClass('highlight').delay(1000).removeClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

I have tried the below suggestions but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you post the HTML that you're applying this to?

Comment: ^ Agreed, the above code should work just fine. jsFiddle would be best

Comment: and a css snip too.  most of the time (in my experience) the li is the highlighted item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try a recursive / callback pattern to add the next element's class as soon as the previous one gets removed.

```
var runner = function (el) {

    var next = el.addClass('highlight').next('.menu-item a');

    setTimeout(function () {
        el.removeClass('highlight');
        next && runner(next);
    }, 1000)        
};

runner($('.menu-item a:first'));
```

Untested code though. I'll see if I can whip up a jsFiddle in a while.

#### EDIT

[Here you go.](http://jsfiddle.net/richardneililagan/evwYe/)

#### EDIT 2

... and that's the reason why you also post the relevant HTML code.

So, considering HTML like:

```
<div id="header">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="menu-item"><a class="menu-item-link">Stage1</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item"><a class="menu-item-link">Stage2</a></li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

use this instead:

```
var items = $('.menu-item a'),
    runner = function (el) {

        var next = items.eq(items.index(el) + 1).addClass('highlight');

        setTimeout(function () {
            el.removeClass('highlight');
            !!next.length && runner(next);
        }, 1000);
    };

runner(items.first());
```

Comment: I could not get this to work. Only the first item is highlighted:

<div id="header">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="menu-item"><a class="menu-item-link">Stage1</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a class="menu-item-link">Stage2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

Comment: With the last code, I can only get the first item to light up :/ it is the same in the first example. And I don't have any other code in my script tag.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a `+ 1` in my second example. If you haven't corrected this yet, try it out.

Comment: Hey Richard, I added the +1, but still nothing happens. I have tried to insert some alert functions to see if the code gets run:

var runner = function (el) {

        var next = items.eq(items.index(el) + 1);
alert("TEST");
        setTimeout(function () {
            el.removeClass('highlight');
            !!next.length && runner(next);
        }, 1000000);
    };

The alert box appears only ONCE, hence there is no recursion. And don't you miss an addClass function to add the highlight effect first?

Comment: Oh now it works. I added el.addClass('highlight') as the first function of the runner method and now it works. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Haha, must have been sleepy or something writing that second piece of code down, sorry for that. I updated my second example to mirror your correction. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".menu-item a").each(function () {
    $(this).addClass("error").delay(1000).queue(function(next){
    $(this).removeClass("error");
   next();
  });
});
```

Comment: I could not get this to work either.

<div id="header">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="menu-item"><a class="menu-item-link">Stage1</a></li>
            <li class="menu-item"><a class="menu-item-link">Stage2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

Comment: This code, highlights all the links at the same time, and after a second removes the highlight on ALL of them at the same time. The other example below works as intended.